# Resolve PROGRAMFILES variable from 32bit app in Win64 OS?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin, system-variable

As explained in MSDN's [WOW64 Implementation Details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384274(v=vs.85).aspx), the variable `%PROGRAMFILES%`,

- in a 32-bit-process on a 64-bit-Windows OS, resolves to `C:\Program Files (x86)`
- in a 64-bit-process on a 64-bit-Windows OS, resolves to `C:\Program Files`

You can verify this e.g. with a Delphi 10.1 program, compiled both with the 32-bit Windows Target Platform and with the 64-bit Windows Target Platform:

```
MyShellExecute('%PROGRAMFILES%');
```

So, from a 32-bit Delphi Application executed in a Windows-64bit-OS, how can I get BOTH:

- the ProgramFiles directory for 32-bit-Programs (`C:\Program Files (x86)`)
- the ProgramFiles directory for 64-bit-Programs (`C:\Program Files`)

Comment: I can't verify that, as I don't have a function `MyShellExecute`, AFAIK.

Comment: @Rudy - That's probably because you forgot to adapt the pronoun; you should try `His/HerShellExecute`. <g>

Comment: @Sertac: Ah, yes, I forgot. <g>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the following environment variables:

- `ProgramW6432` to obtain the 64 bit program files directory.
- `ProgramFiles(x86)` to obtain the 32 bit program files directory.

These return the same values in both 32 and 64 bit processes.

Of course, relying on environment variables is always a little brittle. It's always possible for your parent process to have modified these variables before creating your process.

To make your program more robust you should use [known folder IDs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457.aspx) instead. Use `FOLDERID_ProgramFilesX64` and `FOLDERID_ProgramFilesX86`.

Comment: The `FOLDERID_ProgramFilesX64` is not supported for 32-bit applications running on 64-bit operating systems. Attempting to use FOLDERID_ProgramFilesX64 in this situation results in an error.

Comment: Yes. That's documented in the topics I linked to. From a 64 bit process you can find the 32 bit folder.

Comment: Typically only installers care about the location of these folders so that's not much of a limitation.

Comment: I have a situation here where a ShellLink pointing to a program file in the folder for 64-bit programs resolves to the wrong path in the folder for 32-bit programs when executed in a 32-bit program on 64-bit Windows.

Comment: That sounds odd. I wonder how the link is being resolved. Anyway, that's a different topic. I think I answered the specific question here.

Comment: @user1580348: "*Attempting to use `FOLDERID_ProgramFilesX64` in [a 32 bit app] results in an error*" - your app should detect when it is a 32bit process running on a 32bit or 64bit OS, or running as a 64bit process, and then use the appropriate `KNOWNFOLDERID` for its needs. When compiling for 32bit, use `IsWow64Process()` to know if you are running inside of Wow64 or not.

Comment: For such cases, I use $IFDEFs. The compilr knows best what it is generating.

Comment: @rudy Compiler can't tell whether you are running on 32 or 64 bit system

Comment: @David: that's true. But accessing FOLDERID_ProgramFilesX64 from a 32 bit app is not allowed. The compiler can help me with that. And one can also check the result of GetSpeicalFolderID (or whatever similar function).